# getting error NoLivingConnectionsError in elasticsearch from time to time

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

I'm using the ElasticSearch javascript client. I've several nodejs servers communicating to the elasticsearch.

The elasticsearch is made up of 2 nodes. Where each node has 8GB ram and a quatro core. It is running on Ubuntu 18.04.3 and the elastic search version is 7.6.1
The nodes are successfully communicating with each other.

The problem is that I see NoLivingConnectionsError from time to time. When I get this error, I get it from all the servers that communicate with the elasticsearh.

I opened the logs of elastic search but didn't find any problem there. 
I've on this network also a mongodb and never had problems of communication.

When I restart the elasticsearch service everything works again OK. Mostly it fixes itself after some time.

Does anyone have a direction that they can throw me to find out what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the same issue was reported as part of [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js/issues/829), and to summarize this:

1. You are using multiple nodes in your Elasticsearch client connection.
2. you have configured https for your Elasticsearch sever but not for your client which is also required to configure as per [this](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js/issues/829#issuecomment-487083269) comment.
3. It looks like when you just mention a single host in your client configuration in local it doesn't come.
4. try to disable sniffing.

**Please try disabling the sniffing or just give one node in your elasticsearch configuration, if you are using AWS then better to create ELB and that give in your configuration which we are also doing, in order to change the nodes under ELB and avoid a single point of failure.**

Comment: I've multiple nodes but they are configured with http. I'm not using any sniffing. I just have logs when there are errors in my system. Every single client is working by itself. The problem with only connecting to one node than there is no help of having replication

Comment: so basically you are saying this comes only when you have a single node client ?

Comment: No this isn't what I said. I told that I'm connecting to multiple nodes but with http and not https

Comment: @ElishaSterngold, so given github issue didn't help you ?

Comment: @ElishaSterngold, thanks for awarding the bounty, you made my day :)